# Delete line in a table bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have problem when I try to delete a line in the second page of my table it doesn't work 
and I use this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.supprimer').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id_ts = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        var href = "maj.php?id_ts=" + id_ts + "&param=5";

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: href, 
            success: jQuery("#tr" + id_ts).remove()
        });
    }); 
});
```

Can your help me please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your server side code is actually working, the issue with your javascript is that the `success` property is expecting a function. Try this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: href, 
    success: function(response) {
        jQuery("#tr" + id_ts).remove()
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you give any more detail about why it doesn't work? Any errors in the console? Is your server-side code running?

Comment: yes for the server it work when i delete the first ligne its ok but when i want to delete the second it dosn't do any action even if the ligne is at the same page or at other page of table

Answer (score 0):

it should be like

```
success: function(){
    jQuery("#tr" + id_ts).remove()
})
```